# Simple Fitch Proof

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

after lots of googling i still do not have the answer for this problem.
There are not premisses give, just the goal, which is:
$$((X ∧ Y) ∨ (Y ∧ Z) ∨ (W ∧ Y)) \rightarrow Y$$

Can anyone tell me how to do that fitch proof?
I still don't understand how to start fitch proofs with no premisses.

Thank you guys!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Start with the antecedent as premise and derive the consequent. Then conclude with $\to \text I$. Maybe you have to re-read the initial chapter of your textbook/lectures.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that must be done is to assume the antecedent of your conclusion. The rest follows from using $\wedge$ and $\vee$ elimination.

[image]

Comment: I suppose the software you used can't handle disjunctions with more than $2$ disjuncts?

Comment: @Bram28 you're right. Any recommendations for a better fitch software?

Comment: Not sure if it's 'better' .. but it does support generalized conjunctions and disjunctions: https://proofmood.mindconnect.cc/en/Fitch/fitch.php

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the only way I can solve this with my poor student background. (:

Don't complicate it because there is really no need for it. I prefer this approach. A contradiction is a very last option when you're desperate, just like most of the other methods. 
Notice how simple this expression is:

$Y$ appears inside $3$ brackets $\implies$ $3$ statements in the big $\text{disjunction}$

I applied the $\text{involutarity}$ (if correct):
$$\neg(\neg(P\implies R))\equiv\neg(P\land\neg R)$$

$((X\land Y)\lor (Y\land Z)\lor (W \land Y)) \implies Y\equiv \neg[(X\lor Z\lor W)\land Y\land\neg Y]\equiv\neg[(X\lor Z\lor W)\land 0]\equiv\neg 0\equiv 1\leftarrow\text{tautology}\;\blacksquare$

Answer (score 0):

There a some provers for Fitch proofs in propositional logic:

1. Minlog from Slaney [John Slaney](https://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~jks/): https://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~jks/software/ 
   it is a prover in minimal logic and, as option, in intuitionistic logic too. Here is the output from minlog:

```
 SEQUENT 1:  ((x & y) V (y & z) V (w & y)) -> y
 |- (((x & y) V (y & z)) V (w & y)) -> y

 | ((x & y) V (y & z)) V (w & y)   ASSUMPTION
 |  | (x & y) V (y & z)   ASSUMPTION
 |  |  | x & y   ASSUMPTION
 |  |  | x   &E
 |  |  | y   &E
 |  | 
 |  |  | y & z   ASSUMPTION
 |  |  | y   &E
 |  |  | z   &E
 |  | y   vE
 | 
 |  | w & y   ASSUMPTION
 |  | w   &E
 |  | y   &E
 | y   vE
(((x & y) V (y & z)) V (w & y)) -> y   arrow_I
```

2. [Michel Levy's](https://lig-membres.imag.fr/michel.levy/) prover: http://teachinglogic.univ-grenoble-alpes.fr/DN/  here is its output:

```
1    assume x & y + y & z + w & y.
2      assume x & y + y & z.
3        assume x & y.
4          y.                                              &E2 3
5        therefore x & y => y.                             =>I 3,4
6        assume y & z.
7          y.                                              &E1 6
8        therefore y & z => y.                             =>I 6,7
9        y.                                                +E 2,5,8
10     therefore x & y + y & z => y.                       =>I 2,9
11     assume w & y.
12       y.                                                &E2 11
13     therefore w & y => y.                               =>I 11,12
14     y.                                                  +E 1,10,13
15   therefore x & y + y & z + w & y => y.                 =>I 1,14
```

3. Last, [FLiP](http://staff.washington.edu/jon/flip/www/userguide-nd.html) is a very nice proof checker written by [Jonathan Jacky](http://staff.washington.edu/jon/) in Python and also available [here](https://pypi.org/project/FLiP/).
   With FLiP-1.2,the command

> python -i -m flip.logic.fol_session

import that rules that are defined by [Richard Kaye](http://web.mat.bham.ac.uk/R.W.Kaye/) in [The Mathematics of Logic](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/mathematics-of-logic/52A4112BE9B024B25FC1F69C83BF53DF) and the usual disjunction elimination rule is *not* defined, but replaced by a disjunction elimination right and a disjunction elimination left. If I am not mistaken, the classical rule of double negation elimination seems necessary to prove some theorems with Kaye's rules implemented in FLiP (see Kaye's book, p. 72). For example, in FLiP this theorem of this post is proved as follows (where p,q,r,e replace respectively x,y,z,w):

```
|((p & q) v (q & r)) v (e & q)  (1)  Assumption
||~q                      (2)  Assumption
|||e & q                  (3)  Assumption
|||q                      (4)  And-Elimination (Left) (3)
|||F                      (5)  Contradiction (4) (2)
||~(e & q)                (6)  Reductio Ad Absurdum (3) (5)
||(p & q) v (q & r)       (7)  Or-Elimination (Right) (1) (6)
|||q & r                  (8)  Assumption
|||q                      (9)  And-Elimination (Right) (8)
|||F                     (10)  Contradiction (9) (2)
||~(q & r)               (11)  Reductio Ad Absurdum (8) (10)
||p & q                  (12)  Or-Elimination (Right) (7) (11)
||q                      (13)  And-Elimination (Left) (12)
||F                      (14)  Contradiction (13) (2)
|~~q                     (15)  Reductio Ad Absurdum (2) (14)
|q                       (16)  Not-Elimination (15)
(((p & q) v (q & r)) v (e & q)) -> q (17)  Implication-Introduction (1) (16)
```